# Can HR manipulate (downgrade) appraisal ratings and deny raises and promotions based on it?

Tags: promotion, discrimination

I have been working with this company for the last 3+ years. I never got a raise or promotion, whereas everyone in my group (5+ people) regularly got promotions and raises.

When I found out about this, I sent an email to HR, and here is their reply:

> For the last 2 years your appraisal rating category was F. Even though the client has given a good rating, we need to undergo a normalization process to arrive at the final rating category.

What can I do to address this?

**UPDATE:** So i got a call from director yesterday, 31st was last day to submit the appraisal and i was the only one who did not submit it. We spoke for 15 min.  He acknowledged the issue with ranking system and promised to resolve this issue with in a week. so it worked! Thanks all.

Comment: search the internet for "stack ranking" to learn how this "normalization process" hurts companies and their employees. Whether you think it's BS or not, though, you have very few options other than raising your visibility within your own firm - the client loves you, but apparently nobody in your own firm knows about you.

Comment: Hi otti, welcome to [workplace.se]. Would you mind clarifying, what you want to achieve? You clearly stated your situation, but your post is missing a clearly cut question. "What are my options?" can likely lead to all sorts of answers that might not help you the least bit. Please do clarify. The [help] may serve to guide you in improving this post.

Comment: Thanks, i read about stack ranking, actually the manager i report to is giving me highest possible rating. I spoke to him this morning, according to him i am top performer.

Comment: Why did you not have a meeting with your manager and HR About this after the first time to get better feedback on why?

Comment: Convene a meeting with HR and your manager to find out why there is a massive discrepancy between your manager's appraisal of your performance, and HR's determinations. And then start working on your resume, because no one should have to work in a company like this.

Comment: I was trying to understand why they are downgrading it , is it's legal and what can i do to correct it. I got my answer (i can't do anything) Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most companies rank people and change the ratings the initial manager gives them because they have only so much money to go around. If your rating did not survive the ranking process, then you have to work to have more visibility in the organization and your boss needs to have a reason to go to the mat for you when the senior management team discusses this.

There is nothing in any organization where you more clearly need to play the office politics game than in the performance ratings process. Sure you can opt out of it as you said you did because you didn't like the process. That makes it easy to rate you low and not give you a raise, so it is a stupid move, but hey your own opinion is more important than management's in getting raises any isn't it?

Your immediate boss either

- thinks the other guys who did get raises did better than you (He
  likely had to put all of you in the order he would give raises),
- he has no  political clout in the company (which is why your rating didn't survive),
- or you personally managed to piss off someone senior to him.

In the first case, you need to talk to the boss about what you can do to improve your rating for next year. You will likely need to make some changes to go from the no raise to the raise category.

In the second case, you will need to move to a different organization in the company with a  more politically astute boss or you will need to raise your image among senior managers so that they like you and don't downrate you. Try to get involved in cross functional tasks as a good way to meet and impress higher-ups.

In the third case, you will need to improve your image to whoever is blocking you. Depending on how much you annoyed those people, it may or may not be possible in this company. Based on the fact that this happened over more than one year. it is likely that you have destroyed your reputation with senior management if this is the cause.

In any event, you will never do well as far as raises and promotions until you learn to play office politics. And you need to learn to control that anger and not refuse to participate because you are angry. Letting people know you are angry at work is rarely a winning strategy unless you already have a lot of political power either from your own efforts or positionally. (CEOs have much more latitude to get angry than junior developers for instance.)

Comment: Thanks HLGEM, it's all about money. I think it's time for me to take off because i am working at client's location and cannot take part in any politics.

Answer (score 1):

This smells of rack & stack to me.  As was previously mentioned in a few comments, your options are a bit limited in my opinion.

However, I would mention that these are the types of things you should have also raised or mentioned during your performance review (if you have one).  At that  time of performance review, you could have asked what you needed to improve upon to reach these goals.

If you wish to stay with this company/organization it may be best to have a one-on-one with your direct manager and inquire what they expect of you from your current level in the company, what you need to do to get to the next level and what you can do to better your chances of a raise next review.

Comment: I refused to take part in performance review this year.

Comment: Opaque process to deny raise and promotion.

Comment: @otti so you are asking, "if I don't participate in my companies performance review, can they give me whatever rating they want?"

Comment: No, I refused to take part in performance review "this year". this year i don't care what rating they give me.

Comment: @otti -  I was on your side until I read these comments.  While I understand your frustration withdrawing from the process is not going to make your situation better.

Comment: @otti if you want to withdraw from your company's policies and practices, you do so by getting a new job and resigning, not by "refusing to take part". You are giving an extremely clear picture right now of why you have not been given raises or promotions.

Comment: Civil disobedience is one way to resist BS.

Comment: @otti No one at your company will care and your civil disobedience is only going to get you fired and wreck your career as someone that cannot follow direction.  You're there to do a job for the company and follow their rules while doing so.  The company does not revolve around you.

Comment: @Andy, no one got fired, things got resolved. You and other commenters are scaring people off. I don't know which shi*ty company you worked with and got this notion that solution to every employee related issue is either ignore them or fire them.  There are good companies too, where managers listen and try hard to resolve employees problem. (how you got 1k REP?)

Comment: @otti That's great that things worked out for you, but actively disobeying your company's rules is neither wise nor professional.  You can certainly raise such issues with your manager / employer and work with them to resolve issues, that's fine, "civil disobedience" is not and you're lucky it went the way it did.

Comment: @Andy I am not in Army, it's 9-5 job.

Comment: @Otti and employers can fire for pretty much any reason.  Trying to play those kinds of games are risky.  Good luck.  You'll need it

Comment: @PSU_Kardi yeah it will not work with everyone, some people can get fired.

Comment: @otti I'm not talking about being in the army.  Your employer has policies in place for a reason.  You can disagree, you can try to get the policy changed, but you cannot ignore it just because you feel like it, and companies are free to fire you for doing so, and that's perfectly reasonable.  They might choose to give you one or more warnings first, but they might not.  Its a huge risk to do as you suggest, and other companies may be reluctant to hire you if your behavior becomes know.